# Unable to communicate with Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 and microchipRN4678?

Tags: bluetooth

Unable to communicate with Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 and microchipRN4678?

I want to use the microchipRN4678 Bluetooth module, but communication with devices running OS_Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 does not work.
I get an error related to the COM port.

Communication test between PC running Windows 10 and microchipRN4678 was successful.

About each version,
Windows Embedded Handheld 6.5.3 is Bluetooth 2.0.

microchipRN4678 is bluetooth 4.2 or higher.

Both work fine as long as I can communicate with SPP (serial port profile).

Am I missing something?
Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

([http://www.ruggedpcreview.com/3_handhelds_handheldus_nautiz_x8.html[text]](http://www.ruggedpcreview.com/3_handhelds_handheldus_nautiz_x8.html%5Btext%5D))